# Logs are added in old rotated file instead of new file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Below is my log4j2.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmln="http //logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${path}/server.log"
                 filePattern="${path}/server.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax" />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  
      <RollingFile name="ExceptionLogs" fileName="${path}/ExceptionLogs.log"
                 filePattern="${path}/ExceptionLogs.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax" />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.x.aop.exception">
        <AppenderRef ref="ExceptionLogs"/>
    </Logger>
    
    <Root level="ERROR">
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Let's say my server started at 3:00 PM and I have 5 log files

1. server.log
2. server.log.2022-01-19-15-1  (1 MB)
3. server.log.2022-01-19-15-2  (1 MB)
4. server.log.2022-01-19-15-3  (1 MB)
5. server.log.2022-01-19-15-4  (1 MB)
6. server.log.2022-01-19-15-5  (1 MB)

Some time it will add in older file created (like server.log.2022-01-19-15-2, server.log.2022-01-19-15-1) instead of latest file

Why logs are added in already rotated file instead of latest highest number log file?

Comment: Probably because of this line
`<RollingFile name="ExceptionLogs" fileName="${path}/ExceptionLogs.log"
                 filePattern="${path}/ExceptionLogs.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i">` That `%i` is creating a file everytime it reaches max size 1MB, no?

Comment: Yes, but at current time log should be added in latest file that is 5th rotation or server.log file but it's adding logs in 2nd intex file. It's adding randomly some time in 2nd rotation or some time in latest 5 th rotation